# Apache POI Time Cell

Tags: java, excel, date, time, apache-poi

I need to detect, whether cell format is Date, Time or Datetime.
My code is:

```
        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                if (   ???   )
                    return "Time";
                else if (   ???   )
                    return "Date";
                else
                    return "Datetime";
            }
        }
```

I use ApachePOI 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a built-in way to do this easily in POI.  First, there doesn't seem to be a clear distinction between "Time", "Date", and "Datetime".  The values are just stored as numbers and a format is applied to display it.

One thing you could do is get the style of the cell (`HSSFCellStyle`), then write your own method that reads either `style.getDataFormatString()` or `style.getDataFormat()` and tells you whether the format falls in the "Time", "Date", or "Datetime" category depending on how you define them.  The second method returns an `int` so it might be easier to work with.

For example, the format highlighted below has a String data format of "[$-F400]h:mm:ss\ AM/PM" and an `int` value of 166.

[image: Excel Date/Time Format]

I'm assuming this is what you mean by "Datetime" format, as it's one of Excel's built-in formats that displays both the date and the time.

The drawback of this approach is that I wouldn't expect it to work with cells that have custom date/time formats.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the only good thing we can do here is - to see if time part has value other than zero.
I have tried to use `style.getDataFormatString()` and `style.getDataFormat()` to detect this, but they behave very wrongly for my test cases. Here's my code :

```
private boolean dateIncludesTime() // this method only tries to detect does time part exist, but it is not sure it will succeeed
{
    Date javaDate= (Date)getValue();
    if (javaDate.getHours() > 0 || javaDate.getMinutes() > 0) 
        return true;

    int formatID = apacheCell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat();
    if(formatID >= 18 && formatID <=22) // https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
        return true;

    dateFormat = apacheCell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
    if(dateFormat.toLowerCase().contains("h")) // format mentions hours
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Here's what I get for some test cases :

input 03/21/2015 21:30  getDataFormatString() returns MM/DD/YY     formatID = 165

input 03/21/2016        getDataFormatString() returns MM/DD/YY     formatID = 165

input 2017-04-21 10:20  getDataFormatString() returns YYYY-MM-DD formatID = 166

input 2017-05-21        getDataFormatString() returns YYYY-MM-DD formatID = 166